# How to import entities after save changes with breeze across two entity managers

Tags: breeze, multiple-repositories

I've implemented repository pattern with two entity managers,
mainManager is for read only and delete, and updateManager is used for edit and add new entities. I use createEmptyCopy() to create updateManager.

Before i update an entity i export the entity from mainManager and import into the updateManager, after the change i call to updateManager.saveChanges() method.

I've noticed that i get back the updated entities in the promise response. i wonder what is the best practice to import those entities back into the mainManager?

here is my code:

```
function ($q, $http, entityManagerFactory) {
    var self = this;

    self.mainManager = entityManagerFactory.newManager();
    self.updateManager = entityManagerFactory.newManager();

    self.saveChanges = function () {
        return self.updateManager.saveChanges();
    };

    self.rejectChanges = function() {
        self.updateManager.rejectChanges();
    };

    self.getDomains = function () {
        self.mainManager.clear();

        var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
            .from('Domains')
            .orderBy('name');

        return self.mainManager.executeQuery(query);
    };

    self.createEmptyDomain = function () {
        var domain = self.updateManager.createEntity('Domain');

        return domain;
    };

    self.editDomain = function(domain) {
        var exported = self.mainManager.exportEntities([domain]);
        return self.updateManager.importEntities(exported).entities[0];
    }

    self.addDomain = function (domain) {
        self.updateManager.addEntity(domain);
        return self.updateManager.saveChanges();
    };

    self.deleteDomain = function (domain) {
        domain.entityAspect.setDeleted();
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        self.mainManager.saveChanges().then(
            function(data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            },
            function (reason) {
                console.log(reason);
                self.mainManager.rejectChanges();
                deferred.reject(reason);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}
```

Right now i'm calling mainManager.clear() and get the data again from the server as you can see above in getDomains function.
But i think this is too expansive, why call the server if i already have the updated entities from the saveChanges promise?

i've also tried to import those entities back to mainManager using:

```
mainManager.importEntities(data.entities, { mergeStrategy: breeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges });
```

but i get an internal null breeze exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at EntityManager.proto.importEntities (breeze.debug.js:13081)
    at self.importEntities (domain-list.service.js:22)
    at domain-list.controller.js:70
    at processQueue (angular.js:13170)
    at angular.js:13186
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14383)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14199)
    at Scope.promises.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14488)
    at done (angular.js:9646)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9836)
```

the error is from this line breeze.debug.js:13081

```
13080: var tempKeyMap = {}; 
13081:     json.tempKeys.forEach(function (k) { 
13082:       var oldKey = EntityKey.fromJSON(k, that.metadataStore); 
13083:       // try to use oldKey if not already used in this keyGenerator. 13084:       tempKeyMap[oldKey.toString()] = new EntityKey(oldKey.entityType, 
13085: that.keyGenerator.generateTempKeyValue(oldKey.entityType, oldKey.values[0])); 
13086:     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var exportData = updateManager.exportEntities(data.entities, false);
                 mainManager.importEntities(exportData,
                    { mergeStrategy: breeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges });
```